# PHP textarea into database

Tags: php, html

I'm using textarea to get data that I insert into a database.

I'm using htmlspecialchars() to get rid of the single quotes and double quotes but it doesn't convert new lines into something so I'm left with a very long piece of code that doesn't have new lines and looks messy.

I've checked the manual but I can't find how to convert it.

How would I do this?

EDIT:

My intended output is the same as what the user inputted.

So if they inputted into the textarea...

```
Hi
This is another line
This is another line
```

It would store into the database like...

```
Hi\r\nThis is another line\r\n This is another line.
```

or something like that.

Then when I echo it again then it should be fine.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: Why does it matter what it looks like going into the database?

Comment: 1) Make sure you are *still* using placeholders for SQL access 2) Consider using a *markdown/markup* format and store that instead of "raw" - after automatic conversion as required.

Comment: You can use nl2br either when saving the text or just before you display it. I prefer the second method becuase edits get rather messy when converting to and fro.

Comment: You don't use `htmlspecialchars()` when putting into the DB, you use it when retrieving and displaying. The same thing with `nl2br()`.

Comment: I'd keep the db as clean as possible, and format for output as late as possible...

Comment: I'm using htmlspecialchars() because i'm inserting data that contains quotes and sometimes not quotes. It didn't work before but now it does when I added it...

Comment: @Anthony What Barmar said is still correct. You would use mysql_real_escape_string or mysqli_real_escape_string when inserting. htmlspecialcharacters is for output.

Answer (score 2):

Anthony,

If you are referring to when you get it back out and you want it to look nice, and you aren't putting it back into a textarea, you can use the mythical function nl2br() to convert new line characters into HTML 
 characters.

```
$data = 'Testing\r\nThis\r\nagain!\r\n';
echo nl2br($data);
```

This results in:

```
Testing
This
again!
```

Comment: Why do you claim the function is _mythical_?

Comment: Not many 'newb' peeps know about it. The unknown tends to be mythical

Comment: But we know the truth, which is that it's _real_.

Comment: You do, they don't. Want to play English major on a StackOverflow question comment?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
nl2br($string);
```

That will convert the returns to `<br>` tags

I will also give you this script that has worked well for me in the past when nl2br does not.

```
$remove = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "chr(13)",  "\t", "\0", "\x0B");
$string = str_replace($order, "<br />", $string);
```

Comment: The <br> tags don't get turned into new lines when I take the information from the database. Do I have to run some other function through that variable?

Comment: to pull from the database simply replace `str_replace('<br>','\n\r',$string);`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<?php

addslashes( strip_tags( nl2br( $data ) ) );

?>
```

`addslashes :` will escape quotes to prevent sql injection

`strip_tags :` will remove any html tags if any

`nl2br      :` will convert newline into `<br />`